# Every derived table must have its own alias (

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT sum(DATA.dayMB) as "totaldayMb", 
           data.customerid 
    FROM DATA,customer 
    WHERE data.customerid=customer.customerid 
          AND customer.projectid='"+ ProjectID +"' 
          AND customer.stateid='"+ StateID +"' 
          AND DATA.dataDate between '"+ initialDate +"' 
          AND '"+ finalDate +"' 
          AND data.upstatus='"+upstatus+"' 
    GROUP BY data.customerid 
    ORDER BY sum(DATA.dayMB) desc
   ) 
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
```

In this query I want to select 25 users, who use max data b/w dis date. I am using mysql.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT sum(DATA.dayMB) as "totaldayMb", 
           data.customerid 
    FROM DATA,customer 
    WHERE data.customerid=customer.customerid 
          AND customer.projectid='"+ ProjectID +"' 
          AND customer.stateid='"+ StateID +"' 
          AND DATA.dataDate between '"+ initialDate +"' 
          AND '"+ finalDate +"' 
          AND data.upstatus='"+upstatus+"' 
    GROUP BY data.customerid 
    ORDER BY sum(DATA.dayMB) desc
   ) AS baseview
  LIMIT 25
```

Mind the `AS baseview` in the last-but-one line.

Ofcourse this makes sense, only if the inner query is in the query cache. If not, just use

```
SELECT sum(DATA.dayMB) as "totaldayMb", 
           data.customerid 
FROM DATA,customer 
WHERE data.customerid=customer.customerid 
          AND customer.projectid='"+ ProjectID +"' 
          AND customer.stateid='"+ StateID +"' 
          AND DATA.dataDate between '"+ initialDate +"' 
          AND '"+ finalDate +"' 
          AND data.upstatus='"+upstatus+"' 
GROUP BY data.customerid 
ORDER BY sum(DATA.dayMB) desc
LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the number of returned rows using the `LIMIT` operator ([docu @ MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)) and not with an additional query around it.

That way you also avoid your error.

```
SELECT sum(DATA.dayMB) as "totaldayMb", 
       data.customerid 
FROM DATA,customer 
WHERE data.customerid=customer.customerid 
      AND customer.projectid='"+ ProjectID +"' 
      AND customer.stateid='"+ StateID +"' 
      AND DATA.dataDate between '"+ initialDate +"' 
      AND '"+ finalDate +"' 
      AND data.upstatus='"+upstatus+"' 
GROUP BY data.customerid 
ORDER BY sum(DATA.dayMB) desc
LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: Did you mean `LIMIT 0,25` or `LIMIT 25` ?